# Mysql: I want to compare the results of two queries and return the results

Tags: mysql

In MS Access I have the following query and I want to duplicate it in MysQl

```
SELECT New_Date_Sev54.*
FROM New_Date_Sev54 LEFT JOIN Old_Date_Sev54 ON New_Date_Sev54.[Expr1] = Old_Date_Sev54.[Expr1]
WHERE (((Old_Date_Sev54.Expr1) Is Null));
```

### New_date query :

```
SELECT perimeter.*, perimeter.IP, perimeter.QID, perimeter.Severity, [IP] & [QID] AS Expr1
FROM perimeter
WHERE (((perimeter.QID)<>38628 And (perimeter.QID)<>38675) AND ((perimeter.Severity)=5) AND ((perimeter.Date)=22118)) OR (((perimeter.Severity)=4));
```

### Old Date Query:

```
SELECT perimeter.*, perimeter.IP, perimeter.QID, perimeter.Severity, [IP] & [QID] AS Expr1
FROM perimeter
WHERE (((perimeter.QID)<>38628 And (perimeter.QID)<>38675) AND ((perimeter.Severity)=5) AND ((perimeter.Date)=21918)) OR (((perimeter.Severity)=4));
```

In the ACCESS query, I basically take all the results with the new date and compare them against the results of the old date (week prior) and return anything that did not exist the week prior.

The database is used to quickly identify new vulnerabilities that exist in the perimeter. And is shaped like this

```
Date | IP| VulnID | VulnName | Severity | Threat | Resolution
```

What I have been trying in mysql is using the "NOT IN" comparison of two select statements. However, it is not working.

I want to know all the new vulnerabilities that have a severity of 4 or 5 and that do not have the Vuln id of 32628

Thanks

Comment: Why would do you not use a left join in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Put each query into temp tables:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newVulns AS ([new date query])

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE oldVulns AS ([old date query])
```

where [new date query] and [old date query] are your select statements.

Then

```
SELECT * FROM newVulns n
LEFT JOIN oldVulns o
    ON n.VulnID = o.VulnID
WHERE o.VulnID IS NULL
    AND n.VulnID != 32628 
    AND n.Severity NOT IN (4, 5)
```

I believe that should do it.

Temp table creation info found [in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) and a neat visual representation of joins [can be found here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins). I find myself looking at those all the time.

Comment: DBAs are delicate flowers easily spooked by the unexpected appearance of temporary tables in their systems. Generally speaking one shouldn't alarm them because it puts them off their feed.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I had to do a little modification but it worked fine.